# R: optimal K for KNN model

Tags: r, machine-learning

I am building a K-NN model and trying to find the optimal k but I am not sure which criteria shall I use to compare different k.

Here is the code I am using:

```
dt = matrix(rnorm(150, 10, 2), nrow = 30, ncol = 5)
colnames(dt) = c('true', LETTERS[1:4]) 

index = sample(1:30, 0.5*30)
train = dt[train_index,]
test = dt[-train_index, ]

knn_train = train[, 2:ncol(train)]
knn_test = test[, 2:ncol(train)]
knn_y = train[, 1]
true = test[, 1]

c = rep(0, 10)
for (i in 1:10) {
  knn.pre = FNN::knn.reg(train = knn_train, test = knn_test, y = knn_y, k = i)$pred
  c[i] = mean((knn.pre - true)^2)
}
```

For vector c, I record the MSE of each K-NN model. However, I am not entirely sure it is the case - It seems that for k-means model you could draw a screeplot or using elbow method to find which increase of k drops the marginal difference of **total within-cluster sum of squares** most. See [Sunny Anand's explanation](https://datascienceplus.com/finding-optimal-number-of-clusters/). Is this a similar case for KNN?

How shall I calculate the "total within-cluster sum of square" for KNN models?

It would be great if you could cite for a credible resource. Also, I appreciate if you can provide some info about how to conduct the calculation in R!